# Android Emulator having issues with Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, android-emulator, cordova

I have been using Android and the 2.2 emulator for a bit now and just started running into an issue.  My geolocation is not being set in the Emulator.  At first I thought it was an issue with PhoneGap 0.92 but after reverting to .91 and opening an older project the same holds true.  In DDMS my coordinates are set and I 'send' them.  I also telnet and issue the geo fix command and I get a OK response.  It seems all is well but for some reason the emulator still has no clue.

I found some older posts re: setting the time zone.  I did that.  Still no luck.  I even use the browser and go to html5demos.com/geo to see if it can find me and it does not.

This used to work, not sure what happened since then.  I updated my version of Java 1.6.0.22. Android SDK is 2.2, API 8, revision 2.

Any tips or tricks would be appreciated.  I am stuck at this point.

My Phonegap/JS call:

```
var getLocation = function() {
  var suc = function(p){
        alert(p.coords.latitude + " " + p.coords.longitude);
  };
 var fail = function(error){  
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc,fail);
}
```

The 'fail' keeps happening.  Error code 2.  The last location provider was disabled.

--UPDATE
Still having the same issue.  I found an older mapping application I used back in the summer, it was 2.1.  So I recompiled and ran that on a 2.1 emulator and that is also not working.  The funny thing is in eclipse when i am in DDMS and send coordinates to 2.1 I 'see' a confirmation that it has been sent in the emulator but with 2.2 I do not.

The big difference is I am behind a proxy now (new job) where before I was not.  I guess I could try at home...not sure if that matters.

Comment: have you tried it / is it working on a phone?

Answer (score 13):

You have to put enableHighAccuracy into getCurrentPosition, for example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Next, you have to telnet into the emulator, and geo fix the location(longitude, latitude) you want:

```
kelvin@locahost:~$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix 101.689453 3.074695
OK
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Then run your PhoneGap app.

Comment: awesome, that worked for me, thanks :) oh also note to anyone else trying you need to run the geo fix before each getcurrentposition call, from my experiments.  Could it be more annoying not sure

Comment: @MikeIsrael It would be very hard for it to be more annoying.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I have found to make this work is to telnet to the emulator and issue a "geo fix longitude latitude" after I have triggered the code which I am testing. Something like this emulates GPS coordinates for Trondheim, Norway (the port of the emulator is usually 5554, but this can vary with your settings):

```
kristian@bergman:~$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix 10.40 63.40
OK
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

More information about the emulation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#geo)

Comment: I tested html5demos.com/geo, and that does not work for me either.. But it works for all my own sites...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The solution is at the end of http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation (scroll down):

"Android Quirks

The Android 2.x simulators will not return a geolocation result unless the enableHighAccuracy option is set to true.

{ enableHighAccuracy: true }"

So you have to set enableHighAccuracy at your navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and your navigator.geolocation.watchPosition calls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  But..still no worky :(  I think it is an issue with the emulator (maybe).  First off, every time I fire it up I get the stupid Japanese Keyboard for some reason.  If I then go to a pure HTML5 app that gets location from Chrome, it does not work.  Like this-> http://html5demos.com/geo.  That works in my browser but not on the emulator browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `geolocationOptions { enableHighAccuracy: true }` in `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc,fail);`

It work's for me.

> The Android 2.x simulators will not return a geolocation result unless the enableHighAccuracy option is set to true.

In DDMS my coordinates must set and you 'send' them.