# Google Map + phonegap in android

Tags: cordova

I want to implement Google Maps on android using phonegap and jquery.

I have followed  [this](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1)

The below script is unable to load on android emulator. Even though I have increased the time to 6 min. If i have commented out the below script, i an able to see the screen but not  Google map.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this simple snippet, works on both android and ios. Just put script somewhere in body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.mapReady = function(){
        // you can go with map loaded
};

function loadScript() {     
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.id = 'maps-script';
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
        'callback=mapReady';
   //callback is the name of function to call once map script loaded
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
 //Call to load map script
loadScript();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the URL is not loading or is it this issue here: [Android Emulator having issues with Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169061/android-emulator-having-issues-with-geolocation) where you need to set the geo location for the android simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Here you van find plenty of examples 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_simple_v3 on Google maps APIV3

Answer (score 0):

For future the same person, please try this plugin.
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

You can implement Google Maps into your app easily, and performance is really better than Google Maps JavaScript API v3.
Because this plugin uses Google Maps Android API v2, which render the vector map tile in native side, thus very faster.

[image]